# Selenium Python Using Keys.ARROW_DOWN is different from the manual down arrow key?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Suppose I want to select "May" from a list of months, this is the code I run:

```
while expirymth.text != expiry_mth:
   actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
   sleep(0.5)   
   actions.perform()
   print(expirymth.text)
```

but strangely I get

```
Month #the starting value of the dropdown list
March
July
December
December
December
December
December
...
```

(it will get stuck at December since that's the last month and 'May' is not reached.

However, when I manually press the down-arrow keys, it goes down normally, month-by-month. Sleep, even tried sleep(2), didn't help. I tried running it just once too (as a if function) but I still get March straight away.

Anyone knows why and how to solve this?

Relevant HTML code:

```
function body_onLoad() {
            //                        document.getElementById("card_type").style.display = "none";
            //                        document.getElementById("expiryMonth").style.display = "none";
            //                        document.getElementById("expiryYear").style.display = "none";
            //                        document.getElementById("paymentDescription").style.display = "none";
            refreshAmount();
        }
<tr style="padding:0; border:1px;">
                        <th align="left">Expiry date</th>
                        <td style="padding:0; border:1px; ">
                            <select name="mm" class="required" id="expiryMonth" style="width:160px;font-size:11px;">
                                <option value="">Month</option>
                                <option value="01"  >January</option>
                                <option value="02" >February</option>
                                <option value="03" >March</option>
                                <option value="04" >April</option>
                                <option value="05" >May</option>
                                <option value="06" >June</option>
                                <option value="07" >July</option>
                                <option value="08" >August</option>
                                <option value="09" >September</option>
                                <option value="10" >October</option>
                                <option value="11" >November</option>
                                <option value="12" >December</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
<a class="ui-selectmenu ui-widget ui-state-default required ui-selectmenu-dropdown ui-selectmenu-focus ui-state-hover ui-corner-all" id="expiryMonth_button_881" role="button" href="#" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="expiryMonth_menu_881" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" style="width: 131px;"><span class="ui-selectmenu-status">Month</span><span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></a>

<span class="ui-selectmenu-status">Month</span>
<span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
```

really sorry the code isn't formatted properly, I avoided putting the HTML code because I can't copy it from the page source and it will turn out a bit messy here. Starting from `<a class="ui-selectmenu` it's taken from the "element" section in the web's developer tool and it's not seen in the page source.

Comment: Where is `expirymth` assigned?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use select_by_index to select it instead of action keys. So as you have to select May which has index 5 so,

```
 element= Select(driver.find_element_by_id("expiryMonth"))
 element.select_by_index(5)
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't. I can't use the select element for this form because somehow  I will get the `ElementNotInteractableException: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view` error. And sadly wait, wait until element is located etc doesn't help. using the Select module is just not an option on this page

Comment: can you check if there is any frame involved ?

Comment: how do you check whether a frame is involved?

Comment: There must be iframe tag which is parent to these html